# How can I print to stderr in Dart in a synchronous way?

Tags: dart, dart-io

I'm trying to print a message to stderr. Is there a way to pass the stderr filehandle to print?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Found it:

```
stderr.write("Message");
```

Comment: To use `stderr`, the import `import 'dart:io';` is required.

Comment: `stderr.writeln` is a closer analogue to the `print` function since it prints a *line*.