# print() without a newline in Dart?

Tags: dart

In Dart, I am using `print()` to write content to the console.

Is it possible to use `print()` without it automatically adding a newline to the output?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

You can use `stdout`:

```
import "dart:io";
stdout.write("foo");
```

will print `foo` to the console but not place a `\n` after it.

You can also use `stderr`. See:

[How can I print to stderr in Dart in a synchronous way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12181658/how-can-i-print-to-stderr-in-dart-in-a-synchronous-way)

Answer (score 2):

**1. By using the dart io package**

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  for(int r = 0; r < 5; r++){
    for(int c = 0; c < r; c++){
      stdout.write('Text ');
    }
    print('');
  }
}

Output:
Text 
Text Text 
Text Text Text 
Text Text Text Text
```

**2. By using the direct print() method (Support to Dartpad)**

```
void main() {
  for(int r = 0; r < 5; r++){
    print('Text ' * r);
  }
}

Output:
Text 
Text Text 
Text Text Text 
Text Text Text Text
```

*Example for when multiplying by 0, 1, 2*

```
void main() {
  print('String' * 1);
  print('String' * 0);
  print('String' * 2);
}

Output:
String

StringString
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot customize the print() to prevent printing a newline in Dart (as in Python by using 'end' argument).
To achieve this in Dart, use stdout.write() function, like

```
stdout.write("<your_message>");
```

Answer (score -2):

Have a look are the dcli package you can use the echo function.

```dart
import 'package:dcli/dcli.dart';

void main() {
   echo("hi", newline: false);
}
```