# How to print horizontally to the console in Dart?

Tags: dart, flutter

I've been learning dart for a couple of weeks and here where I was trying to print a stack of starts (*) I discovered that there is no print method to print horizontally. It always creates a new line after it executes the print method.
Here is my code:

```
main(List<String> args){

   for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){

      for(int k =0; k<=i; k++){
        print("*");
      }


   }

}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14073217/print-without-a-newline-in-dart

Comment: Thank you bro. That helped. Just had to imp 'dart:io'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [print() without a newline in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14073217/print-without-a-newline-in-dart)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should write directly to the `stdout` stream:

```
import 'dart:io';

main() {
  stdout.write('*');
  stdout.write('*');
}
```

As an aside, if you want to print the same character multiple times you can multiply strings in Dart!

```
print('*' * 10);
```

will output

```
**********
```