# Write to Flutter console without automatic newline?

Tags: flutter, android-studio

Is there a way to write to the Flutter console in Android Studio without automatically getting a newline carriage-return linefeed at the end?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14073217/print-without-a-newline-in-dart) suggests it's possible in Dart. I've tried that (importing 'dart:io') but to no avail.

What I'm trying to do is use a loop to print a set of values across the line.

Comment: if for some reason this answer isnt working for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14073255/9609442 you could try creating a string above your loop and concatenating new strings to the string in your loop and finally print your string after your loop.

Comment: Good work-around suggestion, thanks. I'm slightly surprised that it doesn't seem possible to do what I'm trying to do - just thought I'd check by asking...

Comment: Yeah it is weird it is not implemented with Flutter, I guess they are focusing more on UI than printing to console...