# How to Read a String from Console in Dart

Tags: dart

I am new to Dart and was wondering if I am able to change the output of stdin.readLineSync() in the terminal. Here is an example of what I want:

```
import "dart:io";
void    main()
{
    print("Insert your name: ");
    String str = stdin.readLineSync()!;
    print("Your name is $str");
}
```

Output

```
Insert your name: 
Max   
Your name is Max
```

Desired output:

```
Insert your name: Max
Your name is Max
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `stdout.write` to print to the  console without a newline.

```dart
import "dart:io";
void    main()
{
    stdout.write("Insert your name: ");
    String str = stdin.readLineSync()!;
    print("Your name is $str");
}
```

Related: [print() without a newline in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14073217/12101554)